# I need to creat a cohort chart in asp.net RDLC report

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, charts, rdlc

Please help i need to create a cohort chart in my  asp.net application like you see in this reference link [http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/Trackback.aspx?guid=d8d11102-05a1-440f-83fa-f473e98825a2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl6OK.png)

so i can do this in RDLC or on my asp.net page dynamically any help or any suggession 
Thanks in Advance

you can see this image i have to develop this in RDLC or in aspx page dynamically ie from database  i have the student enrollement table , year table and their class table any suggession 
[image]
I really appreciate your help thaks

Refference link

http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/Trackback.aspx?guid=d8d11102-05a1-440f-83fa-f473e98825a2

Comment: What research you did so far?

Comment: my research: i think if i creat CTE in SQL and return the result thne it will be possible but its very complex to get the desire result

Comment: i need to creat this in rdlc report. i think the question is quik clr jst read the first 3 lines and see the image thanks

Comment: OR see the Question Title thanks